# Discrete subgroups of the plane isometries group

Tags: geometry, group-theory

What are all the discrete subgroups of the group of plane isometries ?

For finite subgroups, we only have $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $D_n$. (E.g. Fraleigh, A First Course in Abstract Algebra, Theorem 12.5)

What about infinite discrete subgroups ?

Comment: I don't think there is any hope of classfiying those.

Answer (score 5):

You may like to read up on the so called [Frieze Groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frieze_group) and [Wallpaper Groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group). They are classified in terms of the isomorphism class of the orbifolds they generate as orbit spaces of which there are 7 classes of Frieze Groups, and 17 classes of Wallpaper Groups. Many of the groups however happen to share the same isomorphism class as groups. For instance there are two Frieze groups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, the group of integers under addition. And, there are three Frieze groups isomorphic to the infinite dihedral group $\mbox{Dih}_{\infty}$.

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_plane_isometry#Discrete_subgroups.